# Having a field named 'created' within a model - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model such as the following:

```
class Item(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

the admin class is the following:

```
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('name', 'created')
```

the created field does not seem to exist

**Is there some basic Django knowledge that I am missing or have forgotten?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you say the field does not exist, do you mean that it is not showing on the admin change form? This is expected behaviour when using `auto_now_add`. If you want the field to get a default value on creation but still be editable, use `default=datetime.datetime.now` instead.

Comment: +1. Ah. Good interpretation of the question. The field will indeed not show up in the admin add/edit page. It will however show up in the list page.

Answer (score 1):

Strange. I tried out your example and it worked perfectly well (Django 1.2.1, Python 2.6.2)
Can you verify that:

1. The field exists in the database (fire a SQL query perhaps)
2. Check your admin.py (again) for any differences.

**Update**

[@Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635486/having-a-field-named-created-within-a-model-django/3635658#3635658) is more likely to help the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure not to forget registering the ItemAdmin in admin.py:

```
admin.site.register(Item, ItemAdmin)
```

However, the 'created' field would only be displayed in the Item's list page, as well as if you add an additional field such as:

```
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```